# Show specific item when button clicked from list of items in React

Tags: reactjs

i have list of objects. Component iterate through list and returns a button for every item. I want to show a specific item when button clicked. With below code when click a button all items will be shown. How to do that?

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from "react";

const list_of_items = [{id:1, text:"lorem ipsum 1"}, {id:2, text:"lorem ipsum 2"}, {id:3, text: "lorem ipsum 3"}]

function App() {
  const [seeItem, setSeeItem] = useState(false);
  function clickHandler(e) { 
    console.log("Button  clicked ...", e);
    setSeeItem(prevState => !prevState);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Im going to test clicks to list of items</h1>
      {list_of_items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} style={{ margin: 70 }} onClick={clickHandler}>
            { seeItem && JSON.stringify(item)}
            <button style={{display:"block"}}>Which item clicked?</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you want to be able to see more than one item at the time, you need a list of booleans, not just one boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you will need some kind of list to keep track of the items that are showing.

Create the state

```js
const [seeItems, setSeeItems] = useState([]);
```

Create a toggle handler

```js
const toggleSeeItem = (index) => {
  setSeeItems((prevState) => {
    // check if the index is already in the array
    // if so remove it from the list
    if (prevState.includes(index))
      return prevState.filter((item) => item !== index);
    // else the previous array with the new index
    return [...prevState, index];
  });
};
```

Add the `toggleSeeItem` to the onClick and provide the **index**. You can use `includes` to check if the current item should be shown.

```js
{
  list_of_items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div
        key={index}
        style={{ margin: 70 }}
        onClick={() => toggleSeeItem(index)}
      >
        {seeItems.includes(index) && JSON.stringify(item)}
        <button style={{ display: "block" }}>Which item clicked?</button>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanx RubenSmn for your answer. I hoped there was a solution with the event object